# "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64" Error For Node-Api Function Inside "napi-inl.h"

Tags: c++, macos, arm64, node-addon-api

Using Mac M1 Chip, Clang++, and CMake.

I tried to make a node-api addon function using the napi.h given from `npm i node-addon-api` in my frontend. I'm pretty new to using C++.

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <napi.h>

napi_value retrieveData(napi_env env, napi_callback_info info) {
    size_t argc = 1;
    napi_value args[1];
    
    std::string date;
    napi_value output;

    napi_get_cb_info(env, info, &argc, args, NULL, NULL);

    napi_get_value_string_utf8(env, args[0], (char *) &date, (size_t) 5, NULL);

    napi_create_string_utf8(env, (const char*) &date, (size_t) 5, &output);

    return output;
}

napi_value init(napi_env env, napi_value exports) {
    napi_value retrieve;

    napi_create_function(env, nullptr, 0, retrieveData, nullptr, &retrieve);

    return retrieve;
}

NAPI_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, init);
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```cpp
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES "arm64" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)

set (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/clang++" CACHE STRING "C++ compiler" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

project(BCKND)

add_compile_options(-std=c++20 -fcolor-diagnostics -Wall -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpq/15.1/lib -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpqxx/7.7.4/lib -lpqxx -lpq)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

target_link_directories(BCKND PRIVATE /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpq/15.1/lib)
target_link_directories(BCKND PRIVATE /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpqxx/7.7.4/lib)

target_include_directories(BCKND PRIVATE /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpq/15.1/include)
target_include_directories(BCKND PRIVATE /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpqxx/7.7.4/include)
target_include_directories(BCKND PRIVATE /Users/name/project/Frontend/node_modules/node-addon-api)
target_include_directories(BCKND PRIVATE /usr/local/include/node)

target_link_libraries(BCKND pq)
target_link_libraries(BCKND pqxx)
```

However, I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_napi_create_function", referenced from:
      init(napi_env__*, napi_value__*) in main.cpp.o
  "_napi_create_string_utf8", referenced from:
      retrieveData(napi_env__*, napi_callback_info__*) in main.cpp.o
  "_napi_get_cb_info", referenced from:
      retrieveData(napi_env__*, napi_callback_info__*) in main.cpp.o
  "_napi_get_value_string_utf8", referenced from:
      retrieveData(napi_env__*, napi_callback_info__*) in main.cpp.o
  "_napi_module_register", referenced from:
      _register_main() in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

Which I discovered are all in the napi-inl.h header file for node-addon-api
Nothing from napi.h is creating this error like napi_value and napi_env
I'm also using postgresql's libpqxx and libpq which require arm64 to compile.

Tried looking for errors in my CMake, since it is my first time using CMake but I could not find anything and I am unsure how this error is caused and how to fix it. I used different architectures like arm64 and x86_64 but none of them worked. I think I could have included the node-addon-api folder headers wrong or used deprecated functions?

Comment: You need to link to the napi libraries

Comment: @AlanBirtles I can't find any napi libraries, in which directory would I be able to find them? I've looked through node_modules/node-addon-api.

Comment: See https://github.com/cmake-js/cmake-js for instructions